# I achieved hero status, what does it mean?

Tags: immortals-fenyx-rising

I've just defeated the 4 Wraiths, got a trophy stating that now I've achieved the **hero status**, and my health bar in the menu has a slightly different appearance.

Are there any actual benefits with this newly acquired heroic status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, no. As far as I know, nothing special happens, no new skill or Godly power earned.

The only "heroic" thing that you get is...

> your own statue between other Gods.